# Find what am I Riddle?

Tags: riddle

> I can be winding and I can be straight.
>
> I can be smooth and I can be rough, sometimes both.
>
> I start out black but fade to brown the more I am used.
>
> My favorite colors are yellow and white, and I love stripes and dashed lines.

```
What am I?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are

> a **road**.

I can be winding and I can be straight.

> Winding and straight roads.

I can be smooth and I can be rough,Sometimes both.

> Smoothly paved roads or rough cobbled roads.

I start out black but fade to brown the more I am used.

> Freshly paved roads are dark black, but degrade over time.

My favorite colors are yellow and white, and I love stripes and dashed lines.

> Roads are covered in yellow and white stripes and dashed lines.

Comment: Grr!! Beaten by 9 seconds!! Here, take my upvote!

Comment: @Phylyp Doesn't get much closer :)